# Can I prevent the user from stopping my Android application?

Tags: android

The requirement is for an enterprise application. The application will be started on device boot. It will be running in the background and the user should not be able to disable or Stop the application. In Android a user can go to Settings->Application->Manage Application and stop my application. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: if there was any way to do this, everybody could easily make viruses

Comment: I wouldn't tell you how to do that even if I knew.

Comment: two ways: your app reboots the device on termination; use another app started and polled by your app & restarted if terminated which in turn monitors your app and restart it if terminated; use your imagination for more techniques.

Comment: This is a useless feature. If a user wants to kill your app with the task manager, he has a good reason to do so and you shouldn't prevent it. Or it isn't an "enterprise application" as you said...

Comment: This is understandable for typical consumer applications but it would be nice if google would give enterprise applications a way to not be Force Stopped.

Answer (score 1):

No there is not.  You can prevent *Android* from stopping the application by utilizing a Service and marking it as a foreground service, though this will require your application to display an icon in the status bar.

Comment: I'm not even certain that being a foreground service will *prevent* Android from stopping it, though it certainly lowers the odds a great deal.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's true? can please report some google doc that mention this? I'm not worried about honeycomb but for the IceCream

Comment: @JordiCoscolla: Quoting the docs, "It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern." I'm just being pedantic, I suppose. :-)

Comment: Very true, Mark.  In practice I have never witnessed it, but it is theoretically possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can not make your application live forever, but it depends on what you really want to do. It's possible to receive a lot of events of the mobile and execute code even if your Activity/Service is not running. You can use `BroadcastReceivers` to look for interesting events and then start a service. I do it for an Enterprise Application that sends an event to a main server when the user has received/made a call.

Comment: This won't work on Android 3.1+. Apps stopped by the user will be permanently stopped until the user manually launches an activity.

Comment: @CommonsWare that's true? can please report some google doc that mention this? I'm not worried about honeycomb but for the IceCream. 
PD: Sorry I confuse to make the comment (what a shame!)